# I have 3 columns and need to make the middle column stay put when scrolling

Tags: html, css

here is the css:

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1200px;
}

#col1 {
    float: left;
    width: 700px;
}

#col2 {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0 17px;
}

#col3 {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
}
```

I want column 2 to remain at the top of the page once i begin to scroll down. Position fixed doesn't really work as it then screws up the floats.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
#col1 {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

#col2 {
    position:fixed;
    margin-left:500px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0 17px;
}

#col3 {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
}
```

Just needed to use margins with fixed positioning.